# Have we lost critical mass of 3000+ accounts?

Tags: discussion, moderation, closed-questions

Outside of when a moderators step in, I rarely see questions being closed due to receiving votes.  Do we not have enough 3000+ rep people on the site or is the 5 vote limit for close too high?  I'm not sure which is the case here, but the community moderation doesn't really seem to be working.

This isn't a knock on the mods, because you guys seem to be doing a great job.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see a timezone distribution and "most active hours" graph - maybe you're just seeing them when most of the 3k+ users are asleep.

Comment: It's because people who have been here for a while start recognizing the questions that make you stupider for having read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the mods are fast on the ball lately.  If the question stayed around long enough, it would hit the 5 votes.  We have enough 3000+ people right now.

Oh, and as of 7/29/2010 at 10AM EST we have 98 SF users at 3000+ reputation right now.

Comment: It seems to me that it is mostly just having active moderators.

Comment: I was only kidding, it's because of Kyle really.

Comment: I would like to see the moderators have a softer touch in this area myself .. it is easy enough to ignore questions.

Comment: I disagree, tom.  I believe you're in a complete minority.